# Why doesn't this one-line sed command work as I thought it should?

Tags: sed, regular-expression

Running

```
curl -s 'https://www.idealista.com/inmueble/94238881/' \
  -H 'authority: www.idealista.com' \
  -H 'cache-control: max-age=0' \
  -H 'upgrade-insecure-requests: 1' \
  -H 'user-agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/93.0.4577.82 Safari/537.36' \
  -H 'accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.9' \
  -H 'sec-gpc: 1' \
  -H 'sec-fetch-site: same-origin' \
  -H 'sec-fetch-mode: navigate' \
  -H 'sec-fetch-user: ?1' \
  -H 'sec-fetch-dest: document' \
  -H 'referer: https://www.idealista.com/usuario/favoritos/' \
  -H 'accept-language: en-US,en;q=0.9' \
  -H $'cookie: didomi_token=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; euconsent-v2=CPFYMwBPFYMwBAHABBENBXCgAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAEBoFAAVgAuACGAGQAMsAagA2QB2AD8AIAAQUAjABSwCngFXgLQAtIBrADeAHVAPkAhsBDoCKgEXgJEATYAnYBSIC5AGBAMJAYeAxgBk4DOQGeAM-AckA5QB1hKB6AAgABYAFAAMgAcABFADAAMQAeABEACYAFUALgAXwAxABmADaAIQAQ0AiACJAEcAKMAUoAtwBhADKAGqANkAd4A_ACMAEcAKeAVeAtAC0gF1AMUAbgA4gB1AD5AIdARUAi8BIgCbAFigLYAXaAvMBh4DIgGTgMsAZyAzwBnwDSAGsAOAAdYA7UpBQAAXABQAFQAMgAcgA-AEAAIoAYABjADQANQAeQBDAEUAJgATwApABVACwAFwAL4AYgAzABzAEIAIaARABEgCjAFKALEAW4AwgBlADRAGqANkAd8A-wD9AIsARgAjgBKQCggFDAKuAVsAuYBeQDFAG0ANwAegBDoCLwEiAJsATsAocBTQCtgFigLYAXAAuQBdoC8wGGgMPAYwAyIBkgDJwGXAM5AZ4Az6BpAGkwNYA1kBscDkwOUAcuA6wB2oDxyEEIABYAFAAMgAiABcADEAIYATAAqgBcAC-AGIAMwAbwA9ACOAFiAMIAZQA1ABvgDvgH2AfgA_wCMAEcAJSAUEAoYBTwCrwFoAWkAuYBfgDFAG0AOoAegBIICRAEqAJsAU0AsUBaMC2ALaAXAAuQBdoDDwGJAMiAZOAzkBngDPgGiANJAaWA1UBwADkgHRgOsAdqA8cdBxAAXABQAFQAMgAcgA-AEAAIgAXQAwADGAGgAagA8AB9AEMARQAmABPgCqAKwAWIAuAC6AF8AMQAZgA3gBzAD0AIQAQ0AiACJAEdAJYAmABNACjAFKALEAW8AwgDDAGQAMoAaIA1ABsgDfAHeAPaAfYB-gD_AIHARYBGACOQEpASoAoIBTwCrgFigLQAtIBcwC6gF5AL8AYoA2gBuADiQHTAdQA9ACGwEOgIiARUAi8BIICRAEqAJsATsAocBTQCrAFigLQgWwBbIC4AFyALtAXeAvMBgwDCQGGgMPAYkAxgBjwDJAGTgMqAZYAy4BnIDPgGiQNIA0kBpYDTgGqgNYAbGA4uByQHKgOXAdGA6wB44D0gHqhILYACAAFwAUABUADIAHIAPABAACIAGEANAA1AB5AEMARQAmABPgCqAKwAWAAuABvADmAHoAQgAhoBEAESAI6ASwBLgCaAFKALcAYYAyABlwDUANUAbIA7wB7AD4gH2AfoBAACBwEXARgAjQBHACUgFBAKWAU8Aq4BcwC_AGKANYAbQA3ABvADiAHoAPkAhsBDoCLwEiAJiATKAmwBOwChwFIgLFAWgAtgBcgC7wF5gMCAYMAwkBhoDDwGRAMkAZOAy4BnIDPgGkANOgawBrMDkQOVAcuA6MB1gDxxkBwACgAQwAmABcAEcAMsAagA7IB9gH4ARgAjgBSwCrgFbAN4AmIBNgC0QFsALzAYEAw8BkQDOQGeAM-AckA5QVAfAAoAEMAJgAXABHADLAGoAOwAfgBGACOAFLAKvAWgBaQDeAJBATEAmwBTYC2AFyALzAYEAw8BkQDOQGeAM-AbkA5IBygAA.YAAAAAAAAAAA; smc="{}"; userUUID=29668197-3ec8-4380-83a0-af74497d4652; askToSaveAlertPopUp=true; cookieSearch-1="/areas/venta-terrenos/con-precio-hasta_30000,precio-desde_5000,metros-cuadrados-mas-de_500,metros-cuadrados-menos-de_5000,terrenos-urbanos/?shape=%28%28uyxcF%7Cqxl%40%7BxEyrlCput%40ghjBfnw%40%7Dnr%40rlxA%7Dj_AjdWq%60xAr%60r%40_pUvdy%40rwg%40r%7CLr%7BZmfy%40f%7DsB_%7EwBb_aDyj%7DA%7CsoBupaA%7CaO%29%29:1631778650981"; uc="jNLcI107+7z1wRs0x4TdO3u5jcaE+Wrl/o5Drt4SE9qHCxSMOrDfJCS1OVr9tkKQ1xbkhwtCXOZOKw1BLkvMTAMsML+Z10HjHWdUIRhRkRXsEcNnPFEt9rqCk0DCCd7EBSE6A/jp5vs="; nl="wrtrmuF9QzNOYYO2P8SN3OqyjHQXevAY7aYvx0cKdUNwML7qYn47dSs63/pFStgOTH50K6V1y0hMkNG4T70na63g0fJdDSpgDegfruZFCA9GnVx058kgR638a8Q81Gz9r1nzfAqJdfs="; SESSION=2e11a953aead5c1f~d77af03d-2746-4657-89a6-ab25cb02e889; contactd77af03d-2746-4657-89a6-ab25cb02e889="{\'email\':\'EqU9vfX+DxXdzl+iReclTDED4UB/DY6iSfTeSLvLlsE=\',\'phone\':\'634821160\',\'phonePrefix\':null,\'friendEmails\':null,\'name\':\'RL9PoIsz5dW5rvLNF/0gvA==\',\'message\':null,\'message2Friends\':null,\'maxNumberContactsAllow\':10,\'defaultMessage\':true}"; sendd77af03d-2746-4657-89a6-ab25cb02e889="{\'friendsEmail\':null,\'email\':\'EqU9vfX+DxXdzl+iReclTDED4UB/DY6iSfTeSLvLlsE=\',\'message\':null}"; datadome=Gegr2x~z62hH2U.ay-n4sMd3xgi-RaB1X5XMr4i5qV2q6GYsINszxSNDS732-spxaAaUp.m7aGMcOgN-DcAxFY9KCQsldTsDl-RVS5ocEm; cc=eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJjdCI6OTk2MjMyNiwiZXhwIjoxNjMxOTUxOTc4fQ.0YJZGR34jgb1SWTAzL9DFPhAeeP4k0hE9igRE8-SQp0' \
--compressed | grep -m 1 "<meta name=\"description\" content="
```

would give me:

```
<meta name="description" content="terreno de 936 m², Terreno en venta en paseo Blasco Ibáñez s/n, Costa Esuri, Ayamonte, Costa Esuri">
```

In an attempt to scrape just the text, without any HTML, I trialled applying `sed` and I ended up with this code that works as expected:

```
curl -s 'https://www.idealista.com/inmueble/94238881/' \
  -H 'authority: www.idealista.com' \
  -H 'cache-control: max-age=0' \
  -H 'upgrade-insecure-requests: 1' \
  -H 'user-agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/93.0.4577.82 Safari/537.36' \
  -H 'accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.9' \
  -H 'sec-gpc: 1' \
  -H 'sec-fetch-site: same-origin' \
  -H 'sec-fetch-mode: navigate' \
  -H 'sec-fetch-user: ?1' \
  -H 'sec-fetch-dest: document' \
  -H 'referer: https://www.idealista.com/usuario/favoritos/' \
  -H 'accept-language: en-US,en;q=0.9' \
  -H $'cookie: didomi_token=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; euconsent-v2=CPFYMwBPFYMwBAHABBENBXCgAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAEBoFAAVgAuACGAGQAMsAagA2QB2AD8AIAAQUAjABSwCngFXgLQAtIBrADeAHVAPkAhsBDoCKgEXgJEATYAnYBSIC5AGBAMJAYeAxgBk4DOQGeAM-AckA5QB1hKB6AAgABYAFAAMgAcABFADAAMQAeABEACYAFUALgAXwAxABmADaAIQAQ0AiACJAEcAKMAUoAtwBhADKAGqANkAd4A_ACMAEcAKeAVeAtAC0gF1AMUAbgA4gB1AD5AIdARUAi8BIgCbAFigLYAXaAvMBh4DIgGTgMsAZyAzwBnwDSAGsAOAAdYA7UpBQAAXABQAFQAMgAcgA-AEAAIoAYABjADQANQAeQBDAEUAJgATwApABVACwAFwAL4AYgAzABzAEIAIaARABEgCjAFKALEAW4AwgBlADRAGqANkAd8A-wD9AIsARgAjgBKQCggFDAKuAVsAuYBeQDFAG0ANwAegBDoCLwEiAJsATsAocBTQCtgFigLYAXAAuQBdoC8wGGgMPAYwAyIBkgDJwGXAM5AZ4Az6BpAGkwNYA1kBscDkwOUAcuA6wB2oDxyEEIABYAFAAMgAiABcADEAIYATAAqgBcAC-AGIAMwAbwA9ACOAFiAMIAZQA1ABvgDvgH2AfgA_wCMAEcAJSAUEAoYBTwCrwFoAWkAuYBfgDFAG0AOoAegBIICRAEqAJsAU0AsUBaMC2ALaAXAAuQBdoDDwGJAMiAZOAzkBngDPgGiANJAaWA1UBwADkgHRgOsAdqA8cdBxAAXABQAFQAMgAcgA-AEAAIgAXQAwADGAGgAagA8AB9AEMARQAmABPgCqAKwAWIAuAC6AF8AMQAZgA3gBzAD0AIQAQ0AiACJAEdAJYAmABNACjAFKALEAW8AwgDDAGQAMoAaIA1ABsgDfAHeAPaAfYB-gD_AIHARYBGACOQEpASoAoIBTwCrgFigLQAtIBcwC6gF5AL8AYoA2gBuADiQHTAdQA9ACGwEOgIiARUAi8BIICRAEqAJsATsAocBTQCrAFigLQgWwBbIC4AFyALtAXeAvMBgwDCQGGgMPAYkAxgBjwDJAGTgMqAZYAy4BnIDPgGiQNIA0kBpYDTgGqgNYAbGA4uByQHKgOXAdGA6wB44D0gHqhILYACAAFwAUABUADIAHIAPABAACIAGEANAA1AB5AEMARQAmABPgCqAKwAWAAuABvADmAHoAQgAhoBEAESAI6ASwBLgCaAFKALcAYYAyABlwDUANUAbIA7wB7AD4gH2AfoBAACBwEXARgAjQBHACUgFBAKWAU8Aq4BcwC_AGKANYAbQA3ABvADiAHoAPkAhsBDoCLwEiAJiATKAmwBOwChwFIgLFAWgAtgBcgC7wF5gMCAYMAwkBhoDDwGRAMkAZOAy4BnIDPgGkANOgawBrMDkQOVAcuA6MB1gDxxkBwACgAQwAmABcAEcAMsAagA7IB9gH4ARgAjgBSwCrgFbAN4AmIBNgC0QFsALzAYEAw8BkQDOQGeAM-AckA5QVAfAAoAEMAJgAXABHADLAGoAOwAfgBGACOAFLAKvAWgBaQDeAJBATEAmwBTYC2AFyALzAYEAw8BkQDOQGeAM-AbkA5IBygAA.YAAAAAAAAAAA; smc="{}"; userUUID=29668197-3ec8-4380-83a0-af74497d4652; askToSaveAlertPopUp=true; cookieSearch-1="/areas/venta-terrenos/con-precio-hasta_30000,precio-desde_5000,metros-cuadrados-mas-de_500,metros-cuadrados-menos-de_5000,terrenos-urbanos/?shape=%28%28uyxcF%7Cqxl%40%7BxEyrlCput%40ghjBfnw%40%7Dnr%40rlxA%7Dj_AjdWq%60xAr%60r%40_pUvdy%40rwg%40r%7CLr%7BZmfy%40f%7DsB_%7EwBb_aDyj%7DA%7CsoBupaA%7CaO%29%29:1631778650981"; uc="jNLcI107+7z1wRs0x4TdO3u5jcaE+Wrl/o5Drt4SE9qHCxSMOrDfJCS1OVr9tkKQ1xbkhwtCXOZOKw1BLkvMTAMsML+Z10HjHWdUIRhRkRXsEcNnPFEt9rqCk0DCCd7EBSE6A/jp5vs="; nl="wrtrmuF9QzNOYYO2P8SN3OqyjHQXevAY7aYvx0cKdUNwML7qYn47dSs63/pFStgOTH50K6V1y0hMkNG4T70na63g0fJdDSpgDegfruZFCA9GnVx058kgR638a8Q81Gz9r1nzfAqJdfs="; SESSION=2e11a953aead5c1f~d77af03d-2746-4657-89a6-ab25cb02e889; contactd77af03d-2746-4657-89a6-ab25cb02e889="{\'email\':\'EqU9vfX+DxXdzl+iReclTDED4UB/DY6iSfTeSLvLlsE=\',\'phone\':\'634821160\',\'phonePrefix\':null,\'friendEmails\':null,\'name\':\'RL9PoIsz5dW5rvLNF/0gvA==\',\'message\':null,\'message2Friends\':null,\'maxNumberContactsAllow\':10,\'defaultMessage\':true}"; sendd77af03d-2746-4657-89a6-ab25cb02e889="{\'friendsEmail\':null,\'email\':\'EqU9vfX+DxXdzl+iReclTDED4UB/DY6iSfTeSLvLlsE=\',\'message\':null}"; datadome=Gegr2x~z62hH2U.ay-n4sMd3xgi-RaB1X5XMr4i5qV2q6GYsINszxSNDS732-spxaAaUp.m7aGMcOgN-DcAxFY9KCQsldTsDl-RVS5ocEm; cc=eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJjdCI6OTk2MjMyNiwiZXhwIjoxNjMxOTUxOTc4fQ.0YJZGR34jgb1SWTAzL9DFPhAeeP4k0hE9igRE8-SQp0' \
--compressed | grep -m 1 "<meta name=\"description\" content=" | sed -E 's;^.*(content=\");;;s;\">$;;'
```

My question is why doesn't `sed -E 's;^.*(content=\")\">$;;'` work?
It was meant to give me this result:

```
terreno de 936 m², Terreno en venta en paseo Blasco Ibáñez s/n, Costa Esuri, Ayamonte, Costa Esuri
```

wheras it gives me the untrimmed

```
<meta name="description" content="terreno de 936 m², Terreno en venta en paseo Blasco Ibáñez s/n, Costa Esuri, Ayamonte, Costa Esuri">
```

One may need to go to https://www.idealista.com/inmueble/94238881/, then open **developer tools** in their browser and **copy as cURL** in order to play with this example.

Comment: What is `^.*(content=\")\">$` supposed to match? afaics, that will only match something like `... stuff ... content="">`. Only you know how you thought that should work ;-)

Comment: @UncleBilly In response to your comment I just added more information to the question. Later I will delete this comment in order not to clutter USE ;-)

Comment: Matching two consecutive double quotes (`""`) won't match anything. You need someting like `'s#^.*(content=\")([^"]+)\">$#\2#'`.

Comment: Don't parse HTML with regular expressions.  There are far too many ways that can fail.  Use an HTML parser instead.   If you want to write a web bot, I recommend using `perl`, with the [LWP](https://metacpan.org/release/libwww-perl) library or related modules like [WWW::Mechanize](https://metacpan.org/release/WWW-Mechanize) or [Web::Scraper](https://metacpan.org/release/Web-Scraper), or `python` with libs like [Beautiful Soup](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup) or [Mechanize](https://github.com/python-mechanize/mechanize)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two problems with your RegEx. It may be due to a misunderstanding on how RegExes work.

1. You have used the "extended" regular expression syntax, which makes `()` special characters used to denote capture groups. However, they do otherwise not interfere with the matching mechanism itself. Since you don't make use of the capture group, your RegEx amounts to

   ```
   ^.*content=\"\">$
   ```

   which expects the pattern `content=""` with an *empty* quoted string, *and immediately followed by the closing `>`*. This doesn't occur in your input, so `sed` does nothing as no match is achieved. (*By the way, you don't need to escape the `"` - they are not special in RegExes, and your program is in single-quotes, so the shell won't misinterpret the `"` either.*)
2. Even if you correct that, as in

   ```
   ^.*content="[^"]*".*>$
   ```

   you replace the matched part of the line, which due to the anchors is the *entire* line, with the empty string, so in your case, nothing would remain.

To alleviate, you will need to recur to the original idea of using a capture group, but use that to contain the relevant part of the line and then replace the entire line with the content of the capture group, as in:

```
sed -E 's;^.*content="([^"]*)".*$;\1;'
```

This will define the content between the first and next `"` after the `content=` attribute name as capture group, but otherwise match the entire line. It will then replace the entire line with only the content of the capture group via the `\1` expression.